# mule 4 file name pattern

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am trying to read files from an sftp in mule 4 . The files are image files and can be jpg, png, gif etc. As below I am trying to read any of these formats but seems to be picking only the first one.

```
<sftp:matcher filenamePattern="*.jpg, *.png, *.gif" />
```

I tried below also but no luck

```
<sftp:matcher filenamePattern="*.{jpg, png, gif}" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MuleSoft sFTP list operation docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/sftp-connector/1.4/sftp-list), the second pattern you tried should have worked.

The sFTP supports regular expressions too, so you can try the following file name pattern expression:

```
<sftp:matcher filenamePattern="regex:jpg|png|gif" />
```

Comment: Thanks. On second look I had a space between jpg and png for the second pattern I tried. Maybe that could be why.